# How to copy range from one sheet to another column with offset

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a range of data on sheet5 which needs to be copied and inserted 27 columns in from the end of sheet1. I can get it to insert the column in the right place but it doesn't copy the data. I am new to scripting so any advice would be of great help.

Here is code I am using:

```
function store() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();

  var source = ss.getRange ("Sheet5!D4:D80");

  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  var lastCol = destSheet.getLastColumn() -27;

  destSheet.insertColumnAfter(lastCol);

  source.copyTo(destSheet.getRange(lastCol + 1,1), {contentsOnly: true});

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Played today Recorded');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it always the case. You spend hours trying to figure something out, then as soon as you ask someone the answer arrives. For anyone wondering, here is the correct code.

```
function store() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();

  var source = ss.getRange ("Sheet5!D4:D80");

  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  var lastCol = destSheet.getLastColumn() -27;

  destSheet.insertColumnAfter(lastCol);

  source.copyTo(destSheet.getRange(4,lastCol +1,80), {contentsOnly: true});

   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Played today Recorded');
}
```